# When can fcntl() in Linux set errno to EIO?

Tags: linux, system-calls

When calling fcntl() with F_SETLKW, -1 is being returned and errno is being set to EIO. The man page for fcntl on Linux does not indicate that it can set errno to EIO. Various UNIX man pages I have found online reference that it is an input/output error.

What kinds of i/o issues in Linux can cause this errno value when calling fcntl()?

Comment: I guess the right place to look, is the Linux source code.

Comment: Check `errno` *before* the call. It can be the stale value.

Comment: It may depend on the type of file. If it's a _character special_ file, for example, all bets are off.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I would think that if fcntl() is returning -1 that it would also have to set errno, right?

Comment: @BjornA. Thanks. I tried that and do the best of my ability to follow the source I could not find it. It is not trivial to find.

Comment: @JoshuaLee When I look for something in the kernel, I typically start with either "git grep" on a cloned repo, or I index the source tree with cscope and then search from within cscope. These days one can use the browser and search Linus' tree. Probably not the best way to locate where EIO is returned in your case, but here's the link anyway. Best of luck. https://github.com/torvalds/linux/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=EIO&type=

Comment: Final guess, @JoshuaLee. Are you using NFS4? Googling tells me that NFS4 may return EIO for F_SETLKW.

Comment: @BjornA. Unfortunately, no it's NFS3. Thanks!